# Asp.net MVC 5 cannot use Html Helpers in a Razor view inside a class library project

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper, embedded-resource, portable-class-library

Am making a Plugin architecture application using Asp.Net MVC 5 so I created a class library project that will contains some controllers and some embedded Razor views. everything works fine i made some references to the followingDlls `System.Web.Mvc/System.Web.Optimazations/System.Web.Razor/System.Web.WebPages/System.Web.WebPages.Razor/System.Web.helpers.

I added a web.config file and this is what it contains :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />

        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Plugin_1" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" >


    </compilation>

    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="Plugin_1" />
        <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I can use the @model keyword etc but i cannot use html helper like "@Html.ActionLink() etc , @Html is not recognized to vs 2015 !!
Can any one help me please i've seen some similar questions here on StackOF but it doesnt help. and Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make Intellisense show the ASP.NET MVC specific properties you need to change the output path of your class library to `bin`:

Right click project -> Properties -> Build -> change Output path to "bin/"

Now if you open a Razor file in your class library you will get Intellisense for things like `Html.ActionLink`.

Comment: That is the CORRECT answer. thanks Darin. it didnt work for the first time because i didnt not rebuild the app.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add razor reference into project and web config

Comment: i've already did that but still cannot use Html helpers but everything else work fine.